# Little Endian to Big Endian Conversion

Tags: kernel

This is just some curious question, not a problem as such.

I wanted to know if I can change my endianness from **little endian** to **big endian.**

I found this small snippet to check for endianness:

```
echo -n I | od -to2 | head -n1 | cut -f2 -d" " | cut -c6
```

Output on my system:

> 1

### My System Details:

- Linux Mint
- `lsb_release -a`

> No LSB modules are available.
>
> Distributor ID:    LinuxMint
>
> Description:   Linux Mint 19 Tara
>
> Release:   19
>
> Codename:  tara

- uname -r

> 4.15.0-20-generic

Comment: IIRC endianness is property of CPU and cannot be changed, but I dont know how kernel deal with it

Comment: It is a software property or hardware property?

Comment: Hardware, iirc, it defines which order data is stored in CPU registers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change it, it is a hardware property. Big endian machines are IBM mainframes for example. In the the past SPARC processors and IBM Power processors used to be big endian.

Just for a reference, this is from IBM z System machine, you can compare with your x86

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        s390x
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Big Endian
CPU(s):              8
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-7
Thread(s) per core:  2
Core(s) per socket:  8
Socket(s) per book:  3
Book(s) per drawer:  2
Drawer(s):           4
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           IBM/S390
Machine type:        2964
CPU dynamic MHz:     5000
CPU static MHz:      5000
BogoMIPS:            3033.00
Hypervisor:          PR/SM
Hypervisor vendor:   IBM
Virtualization type: full
Dispatching mode:    horizontal
L1d cache:           128K
L1i cache:           96K
L2d cache:           2048K
L2i cache:           2048K
L3 cache:            65536K
L4 cache:            491520K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-7
Flags:               esan3 zarch stfle msa ldisp eimm dfp edat etf3eh highgprs te vx sie
```